# Creating a symlink for Ruby while using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I am following this
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

But i have installed Ruby using RVM as its easy to maintain ruby.

I am at the step to create a symlink for ruby which under this guide it says

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/ruby
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

But since i have used RVM and which i run
`which ruby` i get the following path

```
root@99atoms-staging:~# which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
sudo ln -sfn $(which ruby) /usr/bin/ruby
```

That is essentially the same for you as doing this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: can i use this "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby" as the path for nginx

Comment: If you have used rvm and if you want to set rvm path without symlink then you can use ruby wrapper: `/home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0/wrappers/ruby` It will work!

Comment: @Harsha You can use that path. But it's generally better to use /usr/bin/ruby because you can keep it the same path even when your versions change.